# Unable to send the id using HTTP Post method

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to send the id of a button when it is clicked using HTTP Post method, I've written the following code. But the server is not receiving the id of the button when I press the button. could anyone please guide me, what's going wrong here? Thanks in Advance.

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script>
function fun1(element) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "/prc", true);
    xhttp.send(element.id);
    //alert("ID":element.id);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="fun1(this)" id="img1">IMAGE</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: What's the format the backend expects the data?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) as it has much simpler interface:

```js
function fun1(element) {
  fetch('/prc', { method: 'POST', body: element.id })
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can this "fetch" method be done using XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: @Shubham it's literally a refined API that's should replace xhr.

Comment: I tried using fetch, it's not working, no response from server.